# Single Webscoket for 2 clients

Tags: websocket

I'm trying to build a chat app and i want to use web socket for chat data betwenn two clients.

How can I implement a web socket such that only 2 clients connected to a socket and I want many users  to use the socket simultaniously without them connecting to other sockets so that there wont be unauthorised chat.

example

user 1 and 2 connect to socket at 192.168.0.1/uid1

user 3 and 4 connect to socket at 192.168.0.1/uid2

is something like that possible.

Thanks in Advance.